# Catch word after specific word in a string with -ash

Tags: string, shell, cpu-word, busybox, ash

```
get_channel()
{
    local wifidev="$1"

    set -- $( iw dev "$wifidev" info )
    # e.g. 'Interface wlan0 ifindex 6 wdev 0x2 addr 10:6f:3f:0e:31:8e type IBSS wiphy 0 channel 11 (2462 MHz) NO HT'

    case "$@" in
        *" channel "*)
            while [ "$1" != "channel" ]; do shift; done
            echo "$2"
        ;;
        *)
            return 1
        ;;
    esac
}
```

Looks complicate . I want to have the number after the word "channel",
without sed or awk. Is there maybe a portable 8-) brace-expansion to
just have the word after "channel", something like:

```
channel="${@#*channel }"
set -- $channel
echo $1
```

maybe there is even a better way?

edit: after suggestion we are using this approach for now:

```
set -- $( iw dev "$dev" info )
mychan="$@"
mychan="${mychan#*channel }"
case "$mychan" in
    [0-9]*)
        echo "${mychan%% *}"
    ;;
esac
```

it is fast and safe enough (+portable)- but maybe there is even a nice one?

Comment: thats pretty good. You need to remove remaining after the number witha 2nd brace-expansion, i.e. `channel=${channel%% *}`. Good luck.

Comment: You'd better do `case "$*" in ...` because `"$@"` expand into multiple words, and cause a syntax error for the case statement

Comment: you are right (although at this stage, it's already sanitized - but it doesn't hurt to do it better)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to do anything:

```
${@#* channel }
```

I guess the special parameter $@ is too special.

Store the positional parameters in a tmp variable first

```
local tmp="$*"
tmp=${tmp#* channel }
if [ "$tmp" = "$*" ]; then
    # no "channel" here
    return 1
fi
echo ${tmp%% *}
```

Comment: strange, this does not work here: `echo "${tmp#* channel }"; echo "${tmp% *}"` = `1 (2412 MHz) HT20` and `1 (2412 MHz)` - you can prove that by just feeding "tmp" with the string "Interface..."

Comment: @BastianBittorf, Oops the second needs a double `%%` -- edited answer

Comment: POSIX.1-2008tc1 will leave the effect of using the substring processing expansions like `${parameter#pattern}` on the `*` and `@` special parameters unspecified.

Comment: jilles: this means it is not portable/garanteed to work? so better use a temp-var like glenn proposed?

Comment: Indeed, and in fact behaviour differs between shells (for example applying the substitution to the first element, all elements or the concatenation of all elements with the first character of $IFS).